# Finding string inside an array

Tags: angular

I am trying to find a string inside an array so there is an input box and i type the value to be searched for.
so i created a templated driven form and on submitting it, i stored its value inside variable like

```
onsubmit(){
 let search=this.searchform.value
console.log(search)
}
```

So the value that gets displayed in console is

```
{search: "Bread"}
```

Now  after running the line

```
  let  titles=this.itemlist.map(i=>i.title);
   console.log(titles)
```

i have an array which contains the elements as

```
(2) ["Bread2", "Bread"]
```

How to search for string inside this array like the varaible "search" that gets consoled after submit the form needs to be search within this array

Comment: `array.includes(query)` ... That's a 5 seconds google search.

Comment: This question was asked before, check this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onsubmit(){
  let search = this.searchform.value
  let titles = this.itemlist.map(i=>i.title);

  let found1 = titles.filter(title => title === search.search)
  let found2 = titles.filter(title => title.includes(search.search))
}
```

`found1` includes title that exactly matched. And `found2` includes title that includes `search.search` as substring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a given string exists in the array and retrieve if its index if it does try this js function:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
```

Docs can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try `titles.includes(this.searchform.value)`

or `titles.indexOf(this.searchform.value) > -1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes` function of an array for find value is available in the array or not

```
let result = ["Bread2", "Bread"].includes("Bread");
```

> the result is `true` if the string is in the array

Another way is to find an index like

```
let arr = ["Bread2", "Bread"];
let index = arr.indexOf("Bread");
```

if an index is -1 then this string is not available in array otherwise string is available

```
console.log(arr[index]); //this will give value of string
```

Answer (score -1):

filter like this

```
 let  titles=this.itemlist.map((i)=>
                          {
                            if(i.title===search) return i;
                           });
```